# Microsoft Account not able to sign in after factory reset - Error 80070050

Tags: 8.1, microsoft-account, nokia-lumia-720

So i was using lumia 720 as a daily driver. Downloaded many apps recently through store. But now after factory reset when I try to sign in the microsoft account it says - ( Can't connect . We can't connect at the moment. Wait for a little while and try again). The same problem occurs when i try to install some app. then it shows error (We seem to be experiencing technical difficulties...... This error code may be helpful : 80070057).

Things I have done to solve the problem but not worked.

1. I have checked the date and time and set it manually.
2. Tried both wifi and data connections.
3. Tried changing the language and reseting and then again changing restarting.
4. For region used INDIA - time, date, language.

ALSO have not used Windows insider program to go to any other os (win 10) other than normal OTA updates.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Managed to solve this?